# Virtual Hosts in Go

Tags: http, go, virtualhost

Is there a way to handle listening for multiple Go web applications on a single port (80, for example). I am aware of ServeMux and the ability to listen for different incoming host names, but in this method they must be handled in the same program, and thus the same binary.

Would the best method be to listen for hostnames on :80 in one binary and then send the requests/response writers to another corresponding binary somewhere else? Would I use `"os/exec"` for this? How would you pass in the `Request` and `ResponseWriter` parameters to this external binary? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Is it possible for goroutines of different binary origin to access each others channels? That would be a cool way to do it.

Comment: Regarding your edit: channels can't be used directly for inter-process communication. This is possible in erlang OTP but not in Go. There is however a [RPC package](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual method for doing this would be to use a reverse proxy that directs requests to relevant app servers (usually running on a different port or different machine) based on the host name in the request.

A common approach is to use Apache for this, but if you want to do it from Go, the [`ReverseProxy` type](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy) from the [`net/http/httputil` package](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/) should help.

`httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(baseurl)` will give you an HTTP handler that proxies requests through to another web site and returns the results.  So you could implement your front end via a multiplexing HTTP handler that directs requests to one of a number of `ReverseProxy` handlers based on the requested host name.

If you need more complicated routing than `NewSingleHostReverseProxy` gives you, you can use a custom `Director` function when creating the proxy handler.

Comment: Hey thanks. I have seen your other great Go answers. You wouldn't happen to be Google employee would you?

Comment: Agreed with James, reverse proxy sits on port 80 then maps other running applications as necessary. 
For example, you could have the Apache Reverse Proxy (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) on port 80 - note it works on 443 as well for SSL, or use something like Node.JS as a proxy: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy. That would then have rules to map to other running apps on other ports while still serving to your users on port 80 through the actual proxy itself so its transparent.